# PHP excel From MysQL DATABASE RECORDS

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am trying to download an excel file from MySql database records but i am not getting where i am wrong. Here is my code.

```
    $sql_ft1 = "SELECT `Id`,`fname`,`lname` FROM users";
$rs_ft1  = mysql_query($sql_ft1) or die(mysql_error());
$total1=mysql_num_rows($rs_ft1);
$output.='  <table border="1">  
<tr>  
    <th>Sr NO.</th>  
    <th width="120">User Name</th>  
    <th>Password</th>  
</tr>  
';` while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_ft1))
{`$output.= '  
<tr>  
<td>'.$data["Id"].'</td>  
<td>'.$data["fname"].'</td>  
<td>'.$data["lname"].'</td>  
</tr>  
'; }
$output.='</table>'; 


header("Content-type: application/xls");  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=User_Detail_Reoprt.xls");  

echo $output;
```

i made a new code with ur code as its giving php errors. I changed some " to ' and also in content header i changes filename " but it did not worked

```
$strtable.='<table border="1"><tr><th>Sr NO.</th><th width="120">User Name</th><th>Password</th>';
 $sql_ft1 = "SELECT `Id`,`fname`,`lname` FROM users";
$rs_ft1  = mysql_query($sql_ft1) or die(mysql_error());
$total1=mysql_num_rows($rs_ft1);`    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_ft1)){$strtable.='<tr>

        <td>'.$data["Id"].'</td>  
        <td>'.$data["fname"].'</td>  
        <td>'.$data["lname"].'</td>';
}
$strtable.='</tr>';
$strtable.='</table>';

echo $strtable;
$data = ob_get_contents();`
ob_end_clean();
header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename=User_Detail_Reoprt.xls");`header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print $data;
  echo $filename;
```

Comment: excel is not HTML. Search for libraries to work with XLS(x) files

Comment: PHPEXCEL LIBRARY LINK PLEASE

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$strtable.="<table border="1"><tr><th>Sr NO.</th><th width="120">User Name</th><th>Password</th>";

 $sql_ft1 = "SELECT `Id`,`fname`,`lname` FROM users";
    $rs_ft1  = mysql_query($sql_ft1) or die(mysql_error());
    $total1=mysql_num_rows($rs_ft1);
$strtable.="<tr>
            <td>$data["Id"]</td>
            <td>$data["fname"]</td>
            <td>$data["lname"]</td>";
$strtable.="</tr>";
$strtable.="</table>";
echo $strtable;

$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename="User_Detail_Reoprt.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$data";
```

Comment: Not getting download prompt

Comment: Yes I can  display table with dynamic data

Comment: Then,it should definitely display you a download prompt by using above code.I used same code in my application.It working well for me.check whether you have installed any alert blockers in your browser.

Comment: I have a question . Do I have to include php library to execute my code?

Comment: I told above code as 'my' code with "Try this" title

Comment: Don't need of php libraries,just within open and close php tags..!

Answer (score 0):

change your variable and check result hope it work

```
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);



    $filename = "myfile.xls";
      $header = array("coulmn1","column2");
     $list = array ($header);

foreach($query_result as $result_view){ 
     $list[] = array($result_view->value1,$result_view->value2,
}

$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($list);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); 
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');

            $objWriter->save($filename);
            echo $filename;
```